# Find X position of centered content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the `left` position of any page content (so a single script that works on most of the pages).

What I do now is `$('div').eq(0).offset().left` , so this gets the `left` position of the first div.

The problem now is that many websites (including SO) have a top navbar that is `100% width`, or other absolute-positioned elements that (when placed first in the DOM) will return `left:0px` even though the content is centered.

How can I get the `left` position of the actual content in any webpage?

Possible solutions I have considered:

- Simply skip the div it is not relative positioned.
- Maybe find our content div through the ones that have `margin-left: auto`
- Some websites give their content the ID `content` (including SO)
- Usually the content div is a direct child of the body (SO actually has it inside a wrap)[image]

**LE:**

- The content div is probably the tallest (largest `height`) div in the page.
- Even though header is 100% width, most of the time the first element inside it has the same `left` position as the content

Note that we can talk about this position only on pages that actually have a content div (not 100% full width, not responsive, etc...)

PS: It does not have to work in every case, but something that works on most websites should be ok. Also, any other rule that content div usually has is a great start.

Comment: Notice, that element's position is always related to some other element or view frame. [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) gives you an object containing the position properties of an element related to a view frame.

Comment: @Teemu I have to make this work on desktops only, isn't `jQuery`s `offset()` enough? (I just need to place an element over the content div)

Comment: I know how to place it, the problem is that not every website calls it's content div `#content` so I need to figure out another way to find which `div` is the one that holds the actual content of the page.

Comment: Usually "`#container`" is the element with the largest amount of children.

Comment: I could try all these rules and get the `div` that matches the most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else wants to know this, I have created and used this function:

```
function getContentDiv() {

        var mostProbable = jQuery('div').eq(0);
        var maxP = 0;
        var documentWidth = jQuery(document).width();
        var documentHeight = jQuery(document).height();

        jQuery('div').each(function () {

            var probability = 0;
            var t = jQuery(this);

            if (t.css('position') == 'static' || t.css('position') == 'relative')
                probability += 2;


            if (t.height() > documentHeight / 2)
                probability += 3;

            if (t.parent().is('body'))
                probability++;

            if (t.css('marginLeft') == t.css('marginRight'))
                probability++;


            if (t.attr('id') == 'content')
                probability += 2;


            if (t.attr('id') == 'container')
                probability++;

            if (t.width() != documentWidth)
                probability += 2;

            if (probability > maxP) {
                maxP = probability;
                mostProbable = t;
            }

        });
        return mostProbable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('#divId');
var offset = div.offset();
var left = offset.left;
var top = offset.top;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please read the entire question. The problem is that I do not know the `#divId`. I have to find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could search the body for children with margin set to auto left and use that?

jQuery doesn't return auto but you can find if it is by getting the `margin-left` of the children, resizing the `body` quickly, comparing the `margin-left`, and if any are differing values then that has `margin left: auto`.  Then just get the offset left of that element.

It's not bulletproof obviously - as it's assuming `margin: auto` is only used for centering containers. However, with a few adaptations (like checking for the most common offset left of all children on the same level with `margin: auto`, recursing through lower elements if it hasn't been found) it could work a very high percentage of the time.

Additionally you could check for the presence of a `#content` div with `margin: auto` first.

http://jsfiddle.net/WKgrY/1/

```
function findCentredLeft() {
    var aMargins = [];
    var bW = $('body').width();

    $els = $('div');

    $els.each(function (i, obj) {
        var objML = $(obj).css('marginLeft');
        aMargins.push(objML);
    });

    $('body').width(bW - 1);

    $els.each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(obj).css('marginLeft') != aMargins[i]) {
            left = $(obj).offset().left
            return left;
        }
    });
    $('body').width(bW);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    findCentredLeft();
    console.log(left);
});
```

Comment: `findCentredLeft()` returns `undefined` here on the SO page.

Comment: Because, as you mentioned, it's only going through the first level of items and SO has it's inside a wrapper - it would need to recurse down a level to look for more elements with `margin: auto` or otherwise look for the #content div as mentioned.

Comment: For the time being all that you would need to do for testing is to replace `$('body').children()` with `$('div')`